# show for any A measurable we have $v^+(A)\le\mu_1(A),v^-(A)\le \mu_2(A)$

Tags: real-analysis

The whole problem is as follow:

Let $v$ be a general measure and $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are nonnegative measures 
such that $v = \mu_1-\mu_2$

show for any A measurable we have $v^+(A)\le\mu_1(A),v^-(A)\le \mu_2(A)$

(Hint:$v = (v^++\mu)-(v^-+\mu)$)

I proved first part by:

Let $(P,N)$ be Hahn decomposition about $v$

Since$v=\mu_1-\mu_2 $,so $v\le\mu_1$

$v^+(A) = v(A\cap P)\le\mu_1(A\cap P)\le\mu_1(A)$

But I can't prove $v^-(A)\le\mu_2(A)$

Can someone help?

Comment: Rearrange $\nu^+(A) - \nu^-(A) = \mu_1(A) - \mu_2(A)$.

Comment: I know this, but I don't think it help @DanielFischer

Comment: It should. How did you rearrange?

Comment: $\nu^+ = \nu^-+\mu_1-\mu_2\le\mu_1$,$\nu^-\le\mu_2$? Is that right?@DanielFischer

Comment: It's a bit hard to parse. If your argument goes $\nu^- + \mu_1 - \mu_2 \leqslant \mu_1$ (from rearranging and the inequality $\nu^+ \leqslant \mu_1$), then subtract $\mu_1$ on both sides to get $\nu^- - \mu_2 \leqslant 0$, which it probably does, then it's right.

Comment: @DanielFischer Otherwise, do you think my first part of prove is right?

Comment: You mean the proof that $\nu^+ \leqslant \mu_1$? Yes, that's good. You could also prove $\nu^- \leqslant \mu_2$ in a similar way. $\nu^-(A) = -\nu(A\cap N) \leqslant \mu_2(A\cap N) \leqslant \mu_2(A)$ because $-\nu = \mu_2 - \mu_1 \leqslant \mu_2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you so much